# TikZ externalize with newly defined \includegraphics command fails

Tags: graphics, tikz-external

For a quite large document I'm using the `external` library from `tikz`. However, to annotate an image I tried to include it in a tikzpicture node and then draw on it.

My problem is, that I have defined a new command `\includegraphicscoloured`, which replaces the default `\includegraphics`, such that it supports an additional file suffix (for me "-monochrome" or "-rgb", defined before in the preamble). Now, when I compile the document, my image does not get included, but I only get the text

> [includegraphics optimized away because it does not contribute to exported PDF]

When I use the default `\includegraphics` everything is fine. I can also get it to work, when I globally use `tikzset{external/optimize=false}`, but that is not really an option, since then every single externalisation takes ages.

I tried putting the `external/optimize` key directly at the `tikzpicture` environment or simply inside my newly defined macro, but none of this worked out.

Is there a way that I can switch optimisation off for only that single picture? Or are there things I can modify in the tikzexternalize settings that help? I read the docs, but could not find any details on the process.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[optimize=true]

\def\imageSuffix{-monochrome}

% This line is only here to stop TeXnicCenter from complaining
%   that the image #2\tikzExternalSuffix does not exist
\let\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics   
\newcommand{\includegraphicscoloured}[2][]{%
    % we have to define the filename to test for in a macro,
    %   otherwise it just fails
    \def\testfile{./#2\imageSuffix}%
    %
    % now test if the picture exists as
    %   pdf, png, or jpg
    \IfFileExists{\testfile.pdf}{%
        % pdf version of file exists
        \latexincludegraphics[#1]{#2\imageSuffix}%
    }{%
        \IfFileExists{\testfile.jpg}{%
            % jpg version of file exists
            \latexincludegraphics[#1]{#2\imageSuffix}%
        }{%
            \IfFileExists{\testfile.png}{%
                % png version of file exists
                \latexincludegraphics[#1]{#2\imageSuffix}%
            }{%
                % no known version of the suffixed image exists
                %   thus fallback to normal include, which will
                %   print it's own error when it fails
                \latexincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This works as expected.}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (0, 0) {\includegraphicscoloured[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-b}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This doesn't: ``includegraphics optimized away because it does not contribute to exported PDF''.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Changing the `\let` line to `\def\latexincludegraphics{\includegraphics}` will work.

Comment: @Symbol1: That indeed solved the problem. For anyone else, [this] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318/100384) Stack Exchange question answers the difference between `\let` and `\def`, which probably helps here, too.
Short beginner question, should there be an answer made for this, or would I leave the question open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motivation of `external/optimize` is that when you turn on the externalization, Ti*k*Z will **reread the whole document for every single picture**. An evidence of this is that if you defined, say, `\def\n{100}`, outside `tikzpicture`, Ti*k*Z seems to remember the definition so that you can use `\n` inside the `tikzpicture`. In other words, Ti*k*Z spends a lot of time rereading a bunch of unrelated stuff just to make sure you did not hide the definition of `\n` somewhere deep.

When you turn on `external/optimize`, Ti*k*Z will try to save some time by ignoring expensive macros such as `\includegraphics`. Nonetheless, it will turn on `\includegraphics` while it thinks it need it.

Back to your code: when you say `\let\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics`, you actually finalize the definition of `\latexincludegraphics`; your macro will not be changed even though Ti*K*Z changes the definition of `\includegraphics`. And since by the time you finalize the definition of your macro the `\includegraphics` is turned off, your macro is not going to work properly.

There are two ways to fix this. One is, like I commented, to use `\def` instead of `\let`. By doing so the function of your macro will change whenever Ti*k*Z makes any change. And the other one is to finalized the definition of `\latexincludegraphics` before Ti*k*Z can turn it off.