# How can I use two similar usepackages for many similar commands?

Tags: packages, amsmath, report, mathabx, integral

For example I want to use `\iint` from `ams` package  and also `mathabx` package in one file together. Actually I want a command that neutralizes `ams` package effect and replace it with `mathabx` package effect from here on in my file.
Thanks for your responsibility.

This is my example minimal file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathabx} 
\begin{document}
i want this one in ams style:       
\[
\iiint\,\iiint\, \iiint\,\oint\,
\]
text text text text text text text text text text text text  
and this one in mathabx style:  
\[
\iiint\,\iiint\, \iiint\,\oint\,
\]  
but both of them are the same and i don't like it .....
\end{document}
```

[image: ams]

[image: mathabx]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the first package, save the `\iiint` command in another macro, load the second package (which will redefine the command), save the redefined command in a second macro, and then whenever you want to switch you can redefine `\iiint` to either of the two saved macros. This works if you use `\let`, which saves the command content *at that moment* (see [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def)).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\amsiiint=\iiint
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\abxiiint=\iiint
\let\iiint\amsiiint
\begin{document}
i want this one in ams style:       
\[
\iiint\,\iiint\, \iiint\,\oint\,
\]
text text text text text text text text text text text text  
and this one in mathabx style:  
\let\iiint\abxiiint
\[
\iiint\,\iiint\, \iiint\,\oint\,
\]  
but both of them are the same and i don't like it .....
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear Marijn. But this method doesn't work for below situation. Thanks again

Comment: \usepackage{amsmath}      
\let\amssum=\sum     
\usepackage{mathptmx}     
\let\ptmxsum=\sum     
\let\sum\amssum

Comment: @SH.Madadpour it does work (at least on my computer). You may also want to add an `=` sign for consistency `\let\sum=\amssum`.

Comment: @ marmot Thanks a lot. I put = . But it doesn't work unfortunately. For amsmath and mathabx package is correct But for amsmath and mathptmx is false.

Comment: My answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407129/how-can-i-use-amsmath-package-and-mathptmx-package-together#comment1015293_407129