# Customize 'continues' or \thmcontinues from the thmtools package

Tags: thmtools

The package thmtools offers the parameter 'continues' for theorems as shown in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\itshape,
    notefont=\bfseries\itshape
]{foostyle}

\declaretheorem{foo}[
    style=foostyle
]

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{foo}[Bold note]\label{foo}
        This is the first part.
    \end{foo}
    
    \begin{foo}[continues=foo]
        This is the second part.
    \end{foo}
    
\end{document}
```

I would like to customize this 'continues' parameter. Particularly I want to "unbold" the 'continuing from p. 1' (without removing italic or other attributes). I tried to modify `\thmcontinues` which is defined as

```
\providecommand\thmcontinues[1]{%
\ifcsname hyperref\endcsname
\hyperref[#1]{continuing}
\else
    continuing
\fi
from p.\,\pageref{#1}%
}
```

however renewing did not work (at least the following):

```
\renewcommand\thmcontinues[1]{
    \mdseries\thmcontinues{#1}
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `\renewcommand` is it essentially just allows you to define a command with a previously used name. You want to keep most of the functionality of `\thmcontinues` and add `\mdseries` as well. To do this we create a temporary command, called `\thmcontinuesTEMP` here, and we then renew `\thmcontinues` to be this temporary value and the desired `\mdseries`. To do this use

```
\let{\thmcontinuseTEMP}{\thmcontinues}
\renewcommand{\thmcontinues}{\mdseries\thmcontinuseTEMP}
```

in your preamble and then you should get the following output when you run your MWE:
[image: removed bold from thmcontinues]

Comment: This is good to know! Does it mean that if I write `renewcommand{\thmcontinues}{...}` I cannot use `\thmcontinues` inside the second brackets anymore?

Comment: Yes, if you try to use `\thmcontinues` in definition of `\renewcommand{\thmcontinues}{...}` you will a recursion error, as in the second pair of brackets when you use `\thmcontinues` it will look for the definition which is in the `\renewcommand` which then calls `\thmcontinues` again, etc. until LaTeX gives up. [This is the difference between `\let` and `\def`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def). You can still access `\thmcontinues` behaviour if you use `\thmcontiuesTEMP`