# What is the equivalent PreTeXt equivalent of \def in Latex?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, definition, texdef

I am using Latex to write my course syllabi and I want to switch to PreTeXt does anyone know what is the equivalent of \def in PreTeXt?

For example, in my syllabi I use the following:

\def\officehours{daily at 10am} so that in the main body I can use \officehours instead of daily at 10 am, and I do that with final exam, course name, and so on which allows me to update the preamble and thus update my syllabi without too much effort.

I want to switch to PreTeXt but I haven't found a way to do that. So any help would be much appreciated!

K.

Comment: PreTeXt (nee Mathbook XML) is XML and XSLT.  It can produce TeX, but I don't know that it's on topic for this site.  But maybe look through https://pretextbook.org/doc/guide/html/processing-publisher-stringparam.html ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def)