# \let equivalent in LaTeX2e

Tags: macros, tex-core

I have read in the official [LaTeX2e for class and package writers](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide.pdf) guide (section 2.7.2 "Make it robust") that one should aim to use as many LaTeX commands as possible.

As an example, they suggest to use `newcommand` instead of `def`. Looking at the implementation of `newcommand` described in [source2e](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) it is easy to see that `newcommand` is just layer on top of `def` with additional features.

But what do I use instead of `let`? There are several [sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def) that adress the difference between let and def already, and so my question is, is there a LaTeX equivalent that defines a macro to another macro at point of definition? In other words, I want to create a new macro storing the source code of another macro such that it becomes independent.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\A{A} % original A macro
\A

\let\B\A % B macro is the same as A macro
\renewcommand\A{} % A is now empty (but B is still the old A macro)
\A

\renewcommand\A{\B} % A is now original A again
\A

\end{document}
```

I am interested if there exists a LaTeX alternative to `let`, that replaces `\let\B\A` in the MWE. Something like `\newcommand\B{\A}` but instead of `\B` being the macro `\A` I want `\B` to be the source code of `\A`, so it won't get altered through a `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Note that "\A isn't now original A again" at your last step. The `\A` is macro which expands to `\B` and `\B` expands to `A`. But when you initializes `\A` at the beginning of your test then `\A` expands directly to `A`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to replace `\let` in your example, your `\newcommands` are simple. But if you define commands with an optional argument or robust commands then you should copy them with `\NewCommandCopy` (requires a rather current LaTeX) as that also copies the inner structure.

Comment: Interesting, never heard about `\NewCommandCopy` before, thank you for pointing it out! May I ask what the key differences between `\let` and `\NewCommandCopy` are? As far as I know, commands with an optional argument can also be copied by using `\let`. Is the `\NewCommandCopy` specifically targeted at robust commands? How does `\NewCommandCopy` briefly work? I would appreciate some insights!

Comment: @gyha4 See [LaTeX News Issue 32 (Oct. 2020)](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews32.pdf) and [usrguide3.pdf](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/usrguide3.pdf).

Comment: @frougon Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @gyha4 I'm running MacTeX 2023 and `usrguide3.pdf` doesn't seem to exist any longer but `usrguide.pdf` does.