# Boolean flags allowing CamelCase

Tags: conditionals

In latex, one commonly uses CamelCase.

In my style file' I have

```
\newif\ifMath
\Mathfalse
```

Could these boolean flags be made to allow CamelCase, so the usage is

```
\newif\ifMath
\MathFalse
```

Comment: `\let\Mathfalse\MathFalse`?

Comment: You could do this but I would not.  You could use expl3 booleans or other forms but if using primitive `\if...`  you should follow the language conventions and use `...true` and `...false` to save confusing anyone looking at the code

Comment: @JamesT sorry can you undelete

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I undeleted. If you had a minute, could you go on meta and give some advice on how newbies could get better please

Comment: @JamesT not being confused by wrong advice from old-timers would be a good start:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will definitely remember that one!! Going to quote you later on for sure ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would you be so kind to show an example with `expl3`.

Comment: `texdoc interface3` sec 9.2 or examples https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cbool_if

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own `\NewIf` macro:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\NewIf #1{\expandafter\NewIfA \string#1\relax #1}
\expandafter\def \expandafter\NewIfA \string \If#1\relax #2{%
   \sdef{#1True}{\let#2=\iftrue}%
   \sdef{#1False}{\let#2=\iffalse}%
   \let#2=\iffalse
}

%test:

\NewIf\IfMath

\IfMath Yes\else No\fi

\MathTrue
\IfMath Yes\else No\fi

\MathFalse
\IfMath Yes\else No\fi
```

This macro allows you to use CamelCased `\IfSomething` too. The code above is inspired from `\newif` macro defined in OpTeX.

Comment: it looks odd imho. If one use CamelCase for the first part, then one should use `\Else` and `\Fi`  too. Beside this, in LaTeX I would prefer `\IfMathTF{true}{false}`, that is more consistent with the language.

Comment: +1 I'd wondered if IfMath would be wanted rather than ifMath, this is obviously more general than mine that doesn't define a definition form (you could define `\Else` and `\Fi` for @UlrikeFischer:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree with you but `\IfMathTF` was not the subject of the question. And if someone want to use `\Else`, `\Fi` then `\let\Else=\else`, `\let\Fi=\fi` is the solution. But I understand this question: TeX primitives and standard macros are lowercased and newly defined macros should be CamelCased for more explicit differences. Maybe this is the reason why OP needs such soulution.

Comment: @wipet sorry if I sounded as if tried to critizise your solution, That wasn't the intention, I was actually critizising the goal of the question.

Comment: It would be acceptable to start in lowercase, but the rest use uppercase.  The intention is to distinguish between the various parts.  Thusly `\else` is as readable as `\Else`.  And `\ifMath` is as readable as `\IfMath`.  Starting with uppercase is then not required.  Whilst `\MathTrue` would be more readable than `\Mathtrue`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question so the `community` bot doesn't bump every few months hopefully, if you want to assign a macro or value to be the same as another value or macro, use `\let`, as this [answer by Norman Gray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318/273733) explains.

Simply going `\let\MathFalse\Mathfalse` should assign the value of `\Mathfalse` to `\MathFalse`. If you put this at the start of your style file then you should be able to use CamelCase throughout the rest of the `.sty` file by using `\MathFalse` in lieu of `\Mathfalse`.

Answer (score 2):

you could do this but it breaks the language conventions so it is not a good idea:

Do not use `\newif`, simply do

```
\def\MathTrue{\let\ifMath\iftrue}
\def\MathFalse{\let\ifMath\iffalse}
\MathFalse
```

Comment: If this solution is not recommended, would `\newIf` not be better because one knows it is not the language convention.

Comment: @konmi I don't think I understand your comment. If you only have one or two of these it doesn't seem worth defining  custom definition command, but it doesn't hurt. But I'd use a standard `\newif` with lowercase true and false.

Comment: I could call it `\galexIf` so one knows it is a style setting.  This will be defined in a style file `galex.sty`.  Which will be used in documents using the style file.