# How to change $\epsilon$ to $\varepsilon$ while preserving $\epsilon$ in another command?

Tags: macros, renewcommand

For most of my purposes, I use `\varepsilon`, so I have a `\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}` in my personal .sty file.
A recent homework problem in my numerical calculus class has meant that I would actually need to use the original "lunate" `\epsilon`.
Is there a way to preserve the original `\epsilon` in some other command and then redefine `\epsilon`?
I tried putting `\newcommand{\lunate}{\epsilon}` before my renewal of the `\epsilon` command, but that didn't give the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: `\let\lunate\epsilon` before the `\renewcommand` should work

Comment: That works, but I'm not sure why? What does ``\let`` do differently from ``\newcommand``?

Comment: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def  (`\newcommand` is basically a better `\def`)

Comment: `\newcommand` is basically worse `\def`.