# How to redefine \times such that it shows dot (from \cdot) instead?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to integrate emac's `calc` package (especially `calc-embedded`) into my work flow.

Basically, I'm manipulating / solving equations in `calc`, and then exporting results into LaTeX / org files. (It's really great, I highly recommend `calc`)

However, one thing really bugging me is: `calc` (with latex display mode) uses `\times` symbol for multiplication. I much much prefer `\cdot` instead.

[image]

I tried to fix this by customizing `calc`'s display mode, but no avail. ([link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76282/gnu-calc-how-to-change-default-multiplication-symbol-times-with-cdot-in-l)).

---

It seems, changing `\times` with `\cdot` from latex side seems to be the easier option.

**Basically my question**: how to redefine `\times` such that every time `\times` comes up, latex uses dot (from `\cdot`). And after this redefinition, is it possible to re-use x (from original `\times`)?

Comment: I am not familiar with emac (nor its `calc` package), so this might be totally wrong: What about `\let\oldtimes\times` and `\let\times\cdot`? Then `\times` should give a centered dot and `\oldtimes` a cross.

Comment: @Οὖτις, I think you're right, it's working. Thank you for your answer, Please write your comment as a answer, so I can close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will allow you to get a centered dot via `\times` and a centered cross via `\oldtimes`. Further reading on why I used `\let`: [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258/237192)

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldtimes\times
\let\times\cdot

\begin{document}
    \[   a\times b = c   \qquad   a\oldtimes b = c   \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]